# PonyORM reverse attribute not found error only on one class

Tags: python, flask, ponyorm

I have three table as follow:

```
class User(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "tbl_user"
    idUser = PrimaryKey(uuid.UUID,default = uuid.uuid4 ,column = 'id_user')
    username = Required(str, unique = True)
    email = Required(str, unique = True)
    password = Required(str)
    name = Optional(str,nullable = True)
    gender = Optional(str, nullable = True)
    address = Optional(str,nullable = True)
    birth = Optional(date, nullable = True)
    phoneNumber = Optional(str, column = "phone_number",nullable = True)
    dateRegister = Required(date,column = 'date_register')
    picture = Optional(str, nullable = True)
    isActivated = Required(bool)
    article = Set('Article')
    comment = Set('Comment')
    like = Set('Like')
class Article(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "tbl_article"
    idArticle = PrimaryKey(uuid.UUID,default=uuid.uuid4,column = 'id_article')
    comment = Set('Comment')
    like = Set('Like')
    articleTag = Set('ArticleTag')
    articleCategory = Set('ArticleCategory')
    user = Required(User,column = 'id_user')
    content = Required(Content,column = 'id_content')
class Friend(db.Entity):
    _table_ = "tbl_friend"
    userOne = Required(User,column="id_user_one")
    userTwo = Required(User,column="id_user_two")
    dateFriend = Required(datetime,column="date_friend")
```

When db.generate_mapping() is executed, it throws the following error

```
pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Reverse attribute for Friend.userOne not found
```

When class Friend is removed, the error goes away. I don't understand, why can class Article use User id_user column as foreign key while class Friend throws the reverse attribute error ? What causes this problem and how to fix it ?

Comment: `userOne = Required(User,column="id_user")` The `User` class does not appear to have a `id_user` attribute.  It has `idUser`, perhaps you meant to use that instead?

Comment: @JohnGordon the column name does not have to be the variable name, thats why column="id_user" is there

Comment: Then perhaps the error is that you're using `column="id_user"` for two different attributes?  It doesn't make sense that you're reusing the same column name for two different things.

Comment: @JohnGordon both column require value from column id_user, am i doing it the wrong way? how i should do it?

Comment: The purpose of the `column=` argument is to use a different name for this column, instead of defaulting to the same name as the attribute.  But you're using the same column name for two _different_ attributes, which seems like a mistake.

Comment: @JohnGordon i changed the column to "id_user_one" and "id_user_two" , still throw the same error. I misunderstood the column= argument earlier, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at [Reverse attribute not found in PonyORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523547/reverse-attribute-not-found-in-ponyorm). I had to add Set() attribute to User class. By adding the following to User class

```
friendUserOne = Set('Friend', reverse="userOne")
friendUserTwo = Set('Friend', reverse="userTwo")
```

The problem is fixed. I don't understand why this is a thing in PonyORM, maybe i will look more into this later.